# Axios POST request in react to Express server is returning 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, axios

I am using Axios in my react-app.
Running the react app on server port 3000 and express server on port 31001

My react component--

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from "axios";

export default function Register(){
    let history = useHistory();
    
    function signMeUp(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let userName = document.getElementById('username')?.value
        let password = document.getElementById('password')?.value
        let data = {
            userName:document.getElementById('username')?.value,
            password:document.getElementById('password')?.value,
        }
        
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:31001/register",
            data,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.message);
          });


        console.log(userName, password)
        
        if(userName && password){
            history.push("/Login");
        }
        else{
            alert('Enter a username / password')
        }
    }

    return(
        <div style={{width:"50vw",margin:"auto",marginTop:"50px"}}>
              <h1 style={{textAlign:"center",paddingBottom:"30px"}}>Book My Movie</h1>
              <h1 style={{textAlign:"center"}}>Register</h1>
              <Form onSubmit={(e)=>{signMeUp(e)}}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="username"  />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                    </Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>
              
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" style={{width:"100%"}}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
                <div  style={{textAlign:"center",margin:"auto"}}>
                   <Link to="/Login">Already have a account ? Login Here</Link>
                </div>
              </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My server.js

```
const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 31001,
    cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Backend server live on " + port));

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: "We did it!" });
});
```

I have also placed a proxy on package.json::

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:31001",
```

This is the error i am receiving on chrome console:

```
xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:31001/register 404 (Not Found)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:69)
```

I have read almost all stackoverflow solutions but didnt worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should be `post` in express `app.post("/register", (req, res) => { ..`
because i front-end you're doing  `method: "POST",` :

```
 Axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:31001/register",
            data,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.message);
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting `POST` but you are listening a `GET` request. You have to change the express route to a post request listener.
In this case you will be able to get the request body instead <sup>← *(in case you are sending)*</sup>:

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => { //<---change to post
   res.json({ message: "We did it!" }); // <----res.json to send data as json.
});
```